# Promela syntax error: Error: incomplete structure ref 'table' saw 'operator: ='

Tags: spin, promela

I have the following typedefs. Pub type keeps two ints, and the pub_table keeps an array of publishers and an int.

```
typedef pub{
    int nodeid;
    int tid
};

typedef pub_table{
    pub table[TABLE_SIZE];
    int last
};
```

Then on line `pt.table[pt.last] = p;` I'm getting an error saying

> " Error: incomplete structure ref 'table' saw 'operator: ='"

```
if
:: node_type == publisher -> 
        pub p;
        p.nodeid = node_id;
        p.tid = topic_id;
        pt.last = pt.last + 1; 
        pt.table[pt.last] = p;
fi
```

Unfortunately I cannot see what's wrong on that line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was because you can't assign a complete typedef variable in one go. I tried to do that by defining local variable `pub p;` and then after initializing all fields in p, I tried to assign in one go here `pt.table[pt.last] = p`. I managed to solve it like that:

```
pt.table[pt.last].nodeid = node_id;
pt.table[pt.last].tid = topic_id;
```

[REF](https://spinroot.com/spin/Man/typedef.html):

> The current Spin implementation imposes the following restrictions on
> the use of typedef objects. It is not possible to assign the value of
> a complete typedef object directly to another such object of the same
> type in a single assignment.